# error al composer update mercadopago/dx-php dev-master

Tags: laravel

composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package mercadopago/dx-php dev-master exists as mercadopago/dx-php[1.0, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.6-beta, 1.2.7, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 2.0.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Descargue un carrito de compras en laravel integrado mercado pago
En las indicaciones me dice que corra el comando composer update
pero me sale el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente en esa linea he puesto:
**"mercadopago/dx-php": "^2.0.0"**
Espero no tener inconvenientes

Comment: Para que pones `dev-master`?

Comment: podrías ilustrar?

Comment: Preguntaba porque no entiendo que es lo que intentas hacer. Me imagino que quieres instalar ese paquete vía composer. Si es eso, puedes hacerlo con `composer require nombre-del-paquete`, pero dev-master suena más a ramas de git... Ese paquete en particular ofrece 2 versiones, dependiendo de que versión de php estés usando, por ejemplo `composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:2.0.0"` si usas PHP 7+. Puedes verlo en el readme del paquete https://github.com/mercadopago/dx-php/blob/master/README.md

Comment: hola gracias, he editado la pregunta le he instalado con "mercadopago/dx-php": "^2.0.0" pero de origen viene "dev-master"